# ./configure command no longer available

Tags: source

when installing apache, mysql, php from source ./configure does not a command anymore. What is the replacement for ./configure on ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: `./configure` is still a command. Why do you think it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

`configure` is a script (file) located in the source tree of a source distribution. There is no replacement for it in Ubuntu 13.10, if the source is the same it will still work.

Make sure that you navigated to the source tree of a project. Example instructions that are still applicable:

1. Download source.

   ```
   wget http://bumblebee-project.org/bumblebee-3.2.1.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract source.

   ```
   tar xf bumblebee-3.2.1.tar.gz
   ```
3. Enter extracted source tree.

   ```
   cd bumblebee-3.2.1
   ```
4. Run the `configure` script:

   ```
   ./configure --help
   ```